# console.timeEnd() duped from unknown constructor.js when Debug with Node.js in vscode. What is this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I was learning node.js debugging and I noticed that a `console.timeEnd()` prints twice only when it's run by Debug with Node.js in vscode.

Here's my code:

```
// myConsoleTime.js
console.time('myTask')
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  i + i; // It's myTask
}
console.timeEnd('myTask');
```

And this is the DEBUG CONSOLE tab which is opened by vscode's `Debug with Node.js` button:

[image]

As in the screenshot, due to `constructor.js` which seems to reside in `/internal/console/constructor.js` (definitely no such file on my ubuntu file system), `console.timeEnd()` is somehow printed twice. Moreover, the reported time significantly differs from the first one.

What is this `constructor.js`, and what is the cause of the time difference?

Comment: Have been perplexed with this one the whole day. But it has been declared that there may be some side effects like these here https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/test/inspector/runtime/command-line-api-without-side-effects-expected.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constructor.js` file is from **VSCode's one of the internal file** which is used for debugging Node JS scripts.

It can be found by adding a **breakpoint** to `console.timeEnd('myTask');` and debug.

[image: Add a breakpoint to line 6]

Once Debugger pauses its execution at the breakpoint. Check the **LOADED SCRIPTS** in the left panel. `constructor.js` is available in `<node_internals>/internal/console/constructor.js`

[image]

This file is responsible for the second log that occurred in the console.

[image]

Here is the second log made with the Milliseconds fixed to 3 decimals. And that's why the time difference occurred.

[image]